# How to match all characters between `<` and `>` except `/`?

Tags: java, regex

I want to extract all characters between `<` and `>` except `/`. So if it is `</root>` it should extract `root` and ignore `/`.

This is code for extracting for values between `<` and `>`:

```regex
/<(.*?)>/
```

How do I modify it to ignore `/` but still get the other characters?

Comment: Right off the bat: probably better to just parse your XML if at all possible. That being said, how about just `/<\/?(.*?)>/`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close. Just add an optional slash after the opening pointy brace:

```
</?(.*)>
```

You should also probably not just accept any characters, but exclude the closing pointy brace:

```
</?([^>]*)>
```

The `[^...]` is a negated group that says "anything that's not in the group. The `[` and `]` mark the group, and the `^`  as the first character negates.

That said, it's a really bad idea to parse XML with regular expressions. You should probably look into a XML parser.

If you are not parsing XML and want to exclude the slashes anywhere in the captured text (i.e., not just right after the `<`), you could do a Java text replacement like `result.replace("/", "");`.

Comment: similarly if i need to match all < & > in a string, and not rest, what would be the regex?

Comment: @ajaysingh You'd just use `[<>]`, this is a bracketed group containing the pointy braces.